# Receiving different price than the one I put on iTunesConnect

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm setting price $14.99(consumable product) for `inAppPurchase` on `iTunesConnect` but when I request products, I'm receiving $3.99 against that product in function:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

My `inAppPurchase` is approved. I'm not sure why I'm receiving different price than the one I set on `iTunesConnect`.

Comment: No, you did not set the price to $14.99 (is that USD, CAD, MXP, AUD, etc.?). You set a price tier that has a different value in different countries. Make sure you format the product's price using a `NSNumberFormatter` set to currency and the product's locale.